Is it possible to expose multiple GraphQL endpoints in one spring boot application?
Does Spring support exposing multiple GraphQL endpoints and having separate schemas for those endpoints?
I found nothing about it in the documentation. I know that Spring supports multiple schemas, but as far as I know, all of the schemas are merged into one. This causes naming conflicts and other issues.
Current state:
I already have a Spring GraphQL API in my application with the URL: /old-api/graphql.
To be:

Implement another GraphQL API in the same application.
This API has a different schema, and objects from this schema have naming conflicts with the current one.
I need a different URL for the new API: /new-api/graphql.

Is this possible or not at all? If yes, please provide examples.
I expecting to find a simple way how to solve my problem.
Thanks in advance.

I found how solve the problem by myself. This code based that I found in
GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration and GraphQlAutoConfiguration (from spring-boot-autoconfigure:3.2.2)
Common config:
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.my.app")
@Import({FirstGraphQlConfig.class, SecondGraphQlConfig.class})
public class GraphQlConfig {

  @Bean
  public Instrumentation instrumentation() {
    return new CustomLoggingInstrumentation();
  }

  @Bean
  public AnnotatedControllerConfigurer controllerConfigurer() {
    return new AnnotatedControllerConfigurer();
  }
}

First config:
import graphql.execution.instrumentation.Instrumentation;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.graphql.ExecutionGraphQlService;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.AnnotatedControllerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.BatchLoaderRegistry;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.DataFetcherExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.DefaultBatchLoaderRegistry;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.DefaultExecutionGraphQlService;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.SubscriptionExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.graphql.server.WebGraphQlInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.ServerResponse;

@Configuration
public class FirstGraphQlConfig extends AbstractGraphQlConfig {

  @Bean
  public BatchLoaderRegistry firstBatchLoaderRegistry() {
    return new DefaultBatchLoaderRegistry();
  }

  @Bean
  public GraphQlSource firstGraphQlSource(
      AnnotatedControllerConfigurer controllerConfigurer,
      ObjectProvider<DataFetcherExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers,
      ObjectProvider<SubscriptionExceptionResolver> subscriptionExceptionResolvers,
      ObjectProvider<Instrumentation> instrumentations) {
    return getGraphQlSource(
        "graphql/first.graphqls",
        controllerConfigurer,
        exceptionResolvers,
        subscriptionExceptionResolvers,
        instrumentations);
  }

  @Bean
  public ExecutionGraphQlService firstGraphQlService(
      GraphQlSource firstGraphQlSource, BatchLoaderRegistry firstBatchLoaderRegistry) {
    final var service = new DefaultExecutionGraphQlService(firstGraphQlSource);
    service.addDataLoaderRegistrar(firstBatchLoaderRegistry);
    return service;
  }

  @Bean
  public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> firstRouterFunction(
      ExecutionGraphQlService firstGraphQlService,
      ObjectProvider<WebGraphQlInterceptor> interceptors) {
    return getRouterFunction(
        "/first/graphql", firstGraphQlService, interceptors);
  }
}

Second config:
import graphql.execution.instrumentation.Instrumentation;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.graphql.ExecutionGraphQlService;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.AnnotatedControllerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.BatchLoaderRegistry;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.DataFetcherExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.DefaultBatchLoaderRegistry;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.DefaultExecutionGraphQlService;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.SubscriptionExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.graphql.server.WebGraphQlInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.ServerResponse;

@Configuration
public class SecondGraphQlConfig extends AbstractGraphQlConfig {

  @Bean
  public BatchLoaderRegistry secondLoaderRegistry() {
    return new DefaultBatchLoaderRegistry();
  }

  @Bean
  public GraphQlSource secondGraphQlSource(
      AnnotatedControllerConfigurer controllerConfigurer,
      ObjectProvider<DataFetcherExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers,
      ObjectProvider<SubscriptionExceptionResolver> subscriptionExceptionResolvers,
      ObjectProvider<Instrumentation> instrumentations) {
    return getGraphQlSource(
        "graphql/second.graphqls",
        controllerConfigurer,
        exceptionResolvers,
        subscriptionExceptionResolvers,
        instrumentations);
  }

  @Bean
  public ExecutionGraphQlService secondGraphQlService(
      GraphQlSource secondGraphQlSource, BatchLoaderRegistry secondLoaderRegistry) {
    final var service = new DefaultExecutionGraphQlService(secondGraphQlSource);
    service.addDataLoaderRegistrar(secondLoaderRegistry);
    return service;
  }

  @Bean
  public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> secondRouterFunction(
      ExecutionGraphQlService secondGraphQlService,
      ObjectProvider<WebGraphQlInterceptor> interceptors) {
    return getRouterFunction("/second/graphql", secondGraphQlService, interceptors);
  }
}

Abstract config:
import graphql.execution.instrumentation.Instrumentation;
import java.util.Collections;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.graphql.ExecutionGraphQlService;
import org.springframework.graphql.data.method.annotation.support.AnnotatedControllerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.ConnectionTypeDefinitionConfigurer;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.DataFetcherExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.GraphQlSource;
import org.springframework.graphql.execution.SubscriptionExceptionResolver;
import org.springframework.graphql.server.WebGraphQlHandler;
import org.springframework.graphql.server.WebGraphQlInterceptor;
import org.springframework.graphql.server.webmvc.GraphQlHttpHandler;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.RequestPredicates;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.RouterFunctions;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.ServerRequest;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.function.ServerResponse;

public abstract class AbstractGraphQlConfig {

  private static final MediaType[] SUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPES =
      new MediaType[] {
        MediaType.APPLICATION_GRAPHQL_RESPONSE,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
        MediaType.APPLICATION_GRAPHQL
      };

  protected RouterFunction<ServerResponse> getRouterFunction(
      String path,
      ExecutionGraphQlService service,
      ObjectProvider<WebGraphQlInterceptor> interceptors) {
    final var webGraphQlHandler =
        WebGraphQlHandler.builder(service)
            .interceptors(interceptors.orderedStream().toList())
            .build();

    final var graphQlHttpHandler = new GraphQlHttpHandler(webGraphQlHandler);

    final var graphQlPredicate =
        RequestPredicates.contentType(new MediaType[] {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
            .and(RequestPredicates.accept(SUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPES))
            .and(RequestPredicates.path(path));

    return RouterFunctions.route()
        .GET(path, this::onlyAllowPost)
        .POST(path, graphQlPredicate, graphQlHttpHandler::handleRequest)
        .build();
  }

  protected GraphQlSource getGraphQlSource(
      String schemaPath,
      AnnotatedControllerConfigurer controllerConfigurer,
      ObjectProvider<DataFetcherExceptionResolver> exceptionResolvers,
      ObjectProvider<SubscriptionExceptionResolver> subscriptionExceptionResolvers,
      ObjectProvider<Instrumentation> instrumentations) {
    return GraphQlSource.schemaResourceBuilder()
        .schemaResources(new ClassPathResource(schemaPath))
        .configureTypeDefinitions(new ConnectionTypeDefinitionConfigurer())
        .configureRuntimeWiring(controllerConfigurer)
        .exceptionResolvers(exceptionResolvers.orderedStream().toList())
        .subscriptionExceptionResolvers(subscriptionExceptionResolvers.orderedStream().toList())
        .instrumentation(instrumentations.orderedStream().toList())
        .build();
  }

  private ServerResponse onlyAllowPost(ServerRequest request) {
    return ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
        .headers(this::onlyAllowPost)
        .build();
  }

  private void onlyAllowPost(HttpHeaders headers) {
    headers.setAllow(Collections.singleton(HttpMethod.POST));
  }
}

Disable auto configuration:
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.servlet.GraphQlWebMvcAutoConfiguration, org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.graphql.GraphQlAutoConfiguration


Yes. Spring does supports exposing multiple GraphQL endpoints. You will need to define the resolver classes for each schema definition.
# test1_schema.graphqls
type Query {
    test1: String
}

# test2_schema.graphqls
type Query {
    test2: String
}

Then define the resolver for each.
 @Component
public class Test1Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    public String test1() {
        return "This is test1!";
    }
}

@Component
public class Test2Query implements GraphQLQueryResolver {
    public String test2() {
        return "This is test2!";
    }
}

Then, configure your application to expose multiple GraphQL endpoints, by creating different GraphQlSource beans for each schema.

Thanks for confirming that it is possible. I found a bit different way how to solve my problem.
